# How to increase size of the point of ggplot with new "hits" on that specific ordered pair?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I have a plot like this

```
library(scattermore)
library(ggplot2)

gg <- ggplot()
for (i in 1:6){
   query <- exp_df[[i,1]]
   sup <- exp_df[[i,2]]
   query_path <- paste0(query,".sscore.csv")
   sup_path <- paste0(sup,".sscore%0D.csv")
   shell_command <- sprintf("/bin/bash -c 'paste -d, <(cut -d, -f4 %s) <(cut -d, -f4 %s)'", query_path, sup_path)
   count_pairs <- system(shell_command, intern = TRUE)
   count_pairs_matrix <- as.matrix(read.table(text = count_pairs, sep = ",", header = TRUE, col.names=c("query", "sup")))
   gg <- gg + geom_scattermost(count_pairs_matrix, pointsize=i, pixels=c(700,700))
   }
 }
```

The values x and y can take are between 0 and 2 (integers). How can I progressively increase the size of a point for every added sample at that (x,y) pair. My goal is to visualize which is the most likely combination of x and y.

```
query sup
0 1
2 1
0 0 
...
```

If you have any other suggestions on a different plot than just a scatter one that would be helpful too :)

EDIT: I am using scattermore because I have more than 500k points in each iteration.

Comment: Hi! This is very difficult to help you with because you haven't made a [minimal, reprodubile example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Could you create a minimal dataset that shows your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I the end I just concatenated all my data and grouped it.

```
count <- count_pairs_df %>% count(query, sup)
```

then just plotted the points in count and sized them according to `count$n`